# Show that the variance is biased

Tags: statistics, estimation

I am trying to understand the proof that the uncorrected sample variance is biased (given [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias_of_an_estimator#Sample_variance))

$$
 \begin{eqnarray}
   E[S^2] &=& E \left [ \frac{1}{n} \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n} (X_i - \bar X)^2 \right ] \\
   &=& E \left [ \frac{1}{n} \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n} \left ( (X_i - \mu)- (\bar X - \mu) \right)^2 \right ] \label{eq:s2q1p2p1}\\
   &=& E \left [ \frac{1}{n} \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n} (X_i - \mu)^2 - 2(\bar X -\mu)  \frac{1}{n} \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n} (X_i - \mu) + (\bar X - \mu)^2 \right ]  \\
   &=& E \left [ \frac{1}{n} \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n} (X_i - \mu)^2 -  (\bar X - \mu)^2 \right ]  \\
   &=& \sigma^2 - E \left [(\bar X - \mu)^2 \right ]  < \sigma^2
 \end{eqnarray} 
$$

Conceptually I do understand everything, but I don't understand how to get from

$$
E \left [ \frac{1}{n} \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n} (X_i - \mu)^2 - 2(\bar X -\mu)  \frac{1}{n} \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n} (X_i - \mu) + (\bar X - \mu)^2 \right ]
$$

to

$$
E \left [ \frac{1}{n} \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n} (X_i - \mu)^2 -  (\bar X - \mu)^2 \right ].
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\mu)=n(\bar{X}-\mu)
$$
the second term becomes
$$
-2(\bar{X}-\mu)\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\mu)=-2(\bar{X}-\mu)^2.
$$